# how to open electron application in browser as a local website

Tags: electron

I am trying to open an electron app using localhost but not able to do that. The page in opening but not showing anything?

help.

I tried serve option but the folder where index.html is present there no firing javascript not there. It's in other folder. that's starting javascript.

Comment: Can you provide some code and your folder structure?

Comment: @SebbeBerglönn Yes 'D:\newF\out' => index.html ,, in 'D:\newF\out\scripts\main' there is main file electron.js that has to be fired.